jQuery script does not apply bootstrap classes to my form
**Why does my jQuery code not color the rows when conditions are met (I made the specific part of the script italic)?
**
HTML CODE for the POLL:
<form id="pollForm" class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pitanje1"
              >Koliko ste zadovoljni lokacijom FUTURA Shopping Centra?</label
            >
            <select id="pitanje1" name="pitanje1" class="form-control">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pitanje2"
              >Koliko ste zadovoljni radnjama u FUTURA Shopping Centru?</label
            >
            <select id="pitanje2" name="pitanje2" class="form-control">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pitanje3"
              >Koliko ste zadovoljni izgledom FUTURA Shopping Centra?</label
            >
            <select id="pitanje3" name="pitanje3" class="form-control">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-dark mt-2"
            onclick="saveAnswers()"
          >
            Pošalji
          </button>
        </form>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Pitanja</th>
              <th>Prosečna ocena</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="resultsTableBody">
            <tr id="row1">
              <td>Koliko ste zadovoljni lokacijom FUTURA Shopping Centra?</td>
              <td id="prosecnaOcena1">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row2">
              <td>Koliko ste zadovoljni radnjama u FUTURA Shopping Centru?</td>
              <td id="prosecnaOcena2">0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row3">
              <td>Koliko ste zadovoljni izgledom FUTURA Shopping Centra?</td>
              <td id="prosecnaOcena3">0</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
 

jQuery and bootstrap imports with the logic code:

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const answersData = {
        pitanje1: { ukupnaOcena: 0, brOdgovora: 0 },
        pitanje2: { ukupnaOcena: 0, brOdgovora: 0 },
        pitanje3: { ukupnaOcena: 0, brOdgovora: 0 },
      };

      function saveAnswers() {
        const pitanje1 = parseInt($("#pitanje1").val());
        const pitanje2 = parseInt($("#pitanje2").val());
        const pitanje3 = parseInt($("#pitanje3").val());

        updateAnswer("pitanje1", pitanje1);
        updateAnswer("pitanje2", pitanje2);
        updateAnswer("pitanje3", pitanje3);

        updateResultsTable();
      }

      function updateAnswer(pitanje, vrednost) {
        answersData[pitanje].ukupnaOcena += vrednost;
        answersData[pitanje].brOdgovora++;
      }

      function updateResultsTable() {
        $.each(answersData, function (pitanje, podaci) {
          const srednjaVrednost =
            podaci.ukupnaOcena > 0
              ? (podaci.ukupnaOcena / podaci.brOdgovora).toFixed(2)
              : 0;

          $(`#prosecnaOcena${pitanje.slice(-1)}`).text(srednjaVrednost);

         /*starting from here, until the end of updateResults function*/
        const row = $(`#row${pitanje.slice(-1)}`);

          row.removeClass("bg-danger bg-warning bg-success");

          if (srednjaVrednost < 2.5) {
            row.addClass("bg-danger");
          } else if (srednjaVrednost >= 2.5 && srednjaVrednost <= 3.5) {
            row.addClass("bg-warning");
          } else {
            row.addClass("bg-success");
          }
        });
      }

      $("#pollForm button").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        saveAnswers();
      });
    </script>

I tried writing script that will find out the average of the grades given by user and it all works except the background giving part.

Highlighting doesn't work in code blocks. Please don't put anything there that isn't valid JS code. Use comments to draw attention to specific code lines.

I see you load the Bootstrap JS. Do you load the Bootstrap CSS file?

@Barmar Thanks for the tip on formatting, i edited that. Yes, I do load the bootstrap CSS aswell in the head section.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

There was a default bootstrap class constantly overwriting the bg-success I tried to apply. In the end to get rid of that default class I had to call it in my style.css:
.table {
  --bs-table-bg: none;
}

After that the code began to work properly.
